# CakePHP .htaccess exception for REST API

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, rest, cakephp

I am creating  REST API with CakePHP. 
I have my Angular app in the app/webroot/js folder.
ui-router is working, but I'm trying to get htaccess to make an exception for urls that have /rest/ in them so that I can have rest calls like this:
/rest/posts.json

Here is my app/webroot/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php/#$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^rest/.* rest/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Why is `RewriteRule ^rest/.* rest/$1 [L]` not making an exception to the index.php catchall above it?

Comment: `[L]`tells `mod_rewrite` to stop processing rules if a match is found. `(.*)$`is a catch-all rule. Try moving your last rule to the top. However, you should be able to accomplish what you need with CakePHP without touching your `mod_rewrite` rules.

Comment: Right, but I want to use ui-router. And to do that I need links visited directly to initially have the URI prefixed with a #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answered that yourself, didn't you? The rule above is a *catchall*, it will catch everything, and therefore the following rule will never be reached (unless you are requesting an actual file/directory).

If you'd wanted to point `rest/*` URLs to a different place than `index.php#...`, then you'd have to place it above. However you'd probably start to repeat yourself, as it should be subject to the "not file/directory" conditions too I guess, so I'd probably use a skipping rule for the `FILENAME` conditions, something like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [S=2]
RewriteRule ^rest/.* index.php [L]
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php/#$1 [L]
```

which basically says, if the requested resource is a directory or a file, skip the next two rules, and if it's not, then first check if the current URL starts with `rest/`, and forward it to the normal CakePHP process instead of using the hash append variant.